Click Event on Data Point Plotly Python
I have a simple Plotly Python example script that I am trying to figure out how to add a click callback event to.
What I want to do for demonstration is to add a textbox in the upper right hand corner that will display the coordinates of the data point when I click on it. So far I have the following:
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Replace these with your actual data
data1_x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
data1_y = [2, 4, 5, 3, 1]
data2_x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
data2_y = [3, 1, 4, 2, 5]
data3_x = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
data3_y = [5, 3, 1, 2, 4]

# Create a figure
fig = go.Figure()

# Add traces
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data1_x, y=data1_y, mode='markers', name='Data 1'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data2_x, y=data2_y, mode='markers', name='Data 2'))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data3_x, y=data3_y, mode='markers', name='Data 3'))

# Add a textbox to the top right corner
fig.add_annotation(
    xref="paper", yref="paper",
    x=1.02, y=1.05,
    text="Click on a data point",
    showarrow=False,
    font=dict(size=12)
)

# Define the callback function
def update_text(trace, points, state):
    if points:
        x = points[0].x
        y = points[0].y
        # Format the coordinates as a string
        coordinates = f"({x}, {y})"
        # Update the text of the annotation
        fig.annotations[0].update(text=f"Clicked point: {coordinates}")

# Add the callback to the figure
fig.update_layout(clickmode='event+select')
fig.data[0].on_click(update_text)
fig.data[1].on_click(update_text)
fig.data[2].on_click(update_text)

# Show the plot
fig.write_html('./test_click.html')

I can't seem to get this to work and it does not change the text box at all.
